# Magento: Bulk change product store id

Tags: magento

I've just imported ~800 products into Magento before realising I had store_id set to 0 when it should have been 1.

Does anyone know an easy way to update this? I've tried changing the store_id to 1 in the spreadsheet and importing it again to update them but it hasn't worked.

I found this SQL at http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/1798/ but I'm getting syntax errors and unknown column errors so I've not gone any further with it.

```
REPLACE INTO catalog_product_store (store_id, product_id) SELECT 1,entity_id from catalog_product_entity
update catalog_category_entity set store_id = 1 where store_id = 0;
update catalog_product_entity set store_id = 1 where store_id = 0;
update catalog_product_entity_datetime set store_id = 1 where store_id = 0;
update catalog_product_entity_decimal set store_id = 1 where store_id = 0;
update catalog_product_entity_gallery set store_id = 1 where store_id = 0;
update catalog_product_entity_int set store_id = 1 where store_id = 0;
update catalog_product_entity_text set store_id = 1 where store_id = 0;
update catalog_product_entity_tier_price set store_id = 1 where store_id = 0;
update catalog_product_entity_varchar set store_id = 1 where store_id = 0;
```

Comment: Tried that too :( that's where the unknown column error starts. Is this the best way to do it though?

Comment: Did you try removing them all before re-importing? I don't know what effect that will have, just curious...

Comment: No didn't remove any of them. It was about 840/950 products so couldn't remove via SQL as I couldn't identify which products to remove and thought removing them via the backend would take forever

Comment: the products are not visible in the backend right now?

Comment: They are. What's happening is that even though each product had a properly set category id in the spreadsheet none of them have been assigned to their respective categories. I though it was because a store of ID 0 does not have those categories

Comment: IDs are incremental so the 840 most recent will be #110-#950. You can bulk delete from the Manage Products page. I'm beginning to doubt whether an attribute's store is even relevant, a `store_id` of 0 must mean 'global scope' or 'default values'. I suspect the `catalog_category_product_index` tables are most relevant here.

Comment: Can you not just manage this from the back end of magento?

Comment: My issue is that when I import the products they are not being linked to their categories. I'm not sure why. I have a category_ids column in my spreadsheet. I don't really want to go through each product and assign a category individually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The store ID 0 is the admin store -- it's common to have this set when doing your custom imports. It's not a problem unless you are working with multiple stores.

The quickest way to update your products is to go to your Catalog->Manage Products menu, select all products, and then select "Update Status" and submit. Then you can assign the website association in the Websites tab on the resulting menu.

Bulk edit all products:
[image: Product Bulk Edit]

To do it with code instead, you would want to loop through your product collection and set the website or store id there. An example:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach( $products as $product) {
    $product->setStoreId($storeId);
    try {
        $product->save();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I think I'll create a new question about my category problems

Comment: Glad I could help. You shouldn't really ever use hard SQL -- you are liable to break something. You are getting the error because the SQL you posted doesn't make sense. Those tables do not have a store_id column. At least, not in the EAV model on 1.6.1